# Bounded Variation Functions

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

**My question is;**

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}x^{2} \sin \left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right), & 0<x \leq 1 \\ 0, & x=0\end{array}\right.$

"Show that this function is Bounded Variation on [0,1] or not. "

i know , It's not a bounded variation function.

Because i read a theorem from a book;

where a,b>0 ;

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}x^{a} \sin \left(\frac{1}{x^{b}}\right), & 0<x \leq 1 \\ 0, & x=0\end{array}\right.$

if a>b; f is a bounded variation

if a≤b ; f is not a bounded variation. So; its clear that this function is not bounded variation.

**But i want to solve in different ways. I need your helps. Thanks for your answers.**

Comment: What different ways are you referring to? You stated only the theorem. What are the proof of that theorem?

Comment: Yes, I read its proof but i dont need to write it. because this is not the answer i look for. i mention about chosing a partition in the interval or the  method of deritative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $a_n = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}}$ (which is a monotone sequence in $[0,1]$)

Then the total variation $$V^{\!1}_0(f) \geq \sum_{n=2}^N|f(a_{n-1})-f(a_n)| = \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=2}^N\left(\frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n+1}\right) \xrightarrow{N\to\infty}\infty$$

Comment: it's a very good solution. thanks:) i will look at its details.